# ValueError : Unkown url type in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to shorten urls with bit.ly through django template. I wrote the below templatetag codes, but I'm getting the below error: Can't seems to figure it out all day!

```
ValueError: unkown url type:unknown url type: https%3A//api- ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten%3Faccess_token%3DR_b622c9b2d53899697d6a78c088895f20%26longUrl%3Dhttp%3A//www.google.com%26format%3Dtxt




@register.simple_tag
def bitlys(long_url):
     endpoint='https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}&format=txt'
     req= urllib.quote(endpoint.format(settings.ACCESS_KEY, long_url))
     return urlopen(req).read()
```

Template

```
{% bitlys 'http://www.manman.com' %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably only want to quote long_url and not the whole string

```
endpoint = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}&format=txt'
req = endpoint.format(settings.ACCESS_KEY, urllib.quote(long_url))
return urlopen(req).read()
```

Comment: After following what you said, I put req= urllib.quote(endpoint.format(long_url)) and I'm getting error "tuple index out of range"

Comment: I think access key needs to be included? for it to shorten the url. Kindly explain further what you really meant.

Comment: Your encoding the protocol part of the url when you shouldn't. That's why "api-ssl.bitly.com"; looks like "https%3A//api-ssl.bitly.com"

    `endpoint = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=%s&longUrl=%s&format=txt' % (settings.ACCESS_KEY, urllib.quote(long_url))
    return urlopen(endpoint).read()`

Comment: or if you want to use "format"

`endpoint = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token={0}&longUrl={1}&format=txt'
req = endpoint.format(settings.ACCESS_KEY, urllib.quote(long_url))
return urlopen(req).read()`

Comment: Seriously, you rock! Kindly put it in answer so other people who might have this problem can see. Thanks so much!